# Cleaning echo $PATH on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, path, environment-variables

I'm struggling to completely understand the path settings on my centos os. I make sure to always have what I need set in .bashrc but then when I run `echo $PATH` I get a ton of stuff and duplication I don't want part of the path. Where does it get this from and how can I clean up all of what is in there to only reflect what I'm putting in .bashrc. This is also causing my system to read a binary I don't want it to find because it is located in `echo $PATH`. Here is my full result of `echo $PATH`:

```
PATH=/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/ebs/wfx-etl/scripts:/ebs/config:/usr/local/go/bin:/ebs/spark1.5/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/ebs/wfx-etl/scripts:/ebs/config:/usr/local/go/bin:/ebs/spark1.5/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/ebs/wfx-etl/scripts:/ebs/config:/usr/local/go/bin:/ebs/spark1.5/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/ebs/wfx-etl/scripts:/ebs/config:/usr/local/go/bin:/ebs/spark1.5/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/ebs/wfx-etl/scripts:/ebs/config:/usr/local/go/bin:/ebs/spark1.5/bin:/ebs/anaconda3/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/maven/bin:/ebs/wfx-etl/scripts:/ebs/config:/usr/local/go/bin:/ebs/spark1.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

And here is what I have in my .bashrc:

```
export SBT_HOME=/usr/local/sbt
export R_HOME=/usr/local/R-3.1.2
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_60
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/jre
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/maven
export SPARK_HOME=/ebs/spark1.5
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${JRE_HOME}/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:${M2_HOME}/bin:/ebs/wfx-etl/scripts:/ebs/config:/usr/local/go/bin:${SPARK_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/ebs/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
export PGPASSFILE=$HOME/.pgpass.conf
export EDITOR=vim
```

Comment: Can you share what you're doing in `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 1):

You can override it completely in your `.bashrc` like this:

```
export PATH=/foo/bar:/baz/quux
```

Substitute whatever paths you like, but be advised if you miss out `/bin` or `/usr/bin` you will be sorry.

Comment: That's not a good idea. Your system administrator may have directories on the `PATH` your shell inherits on startup that you shouldn't get rid of.

Comment: I added my current bashrc to the question. So i was under the impression that I am already using export statements in my bashrc and was assuming it would over-ride everything. still not sure where all the stuff from `echo $PATH` is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Java delevopment kit (jdk) who set all that path.
and i suppose it's useful. you have anaconda 3 too for python.

or you can lunch your bash/zsh with `env -i` to set a empty environment

```
env -i bash

env -i zsh
```